# Facebook like counter appears after pressing "Like", then resets a second later

Tags: javascript, facebook

We're having issues with our Facebook like button.  It works perfectly most of the time, but every once in a while it won't "hold' the like count, you'll press like and it will change from the blue button to the grey "liked" button, and then less then a second later reset to the blue like button as though it had not been pressed.

Here's an example of a campaign that is working fine:
www.teespring.com/hjkl

Here's an example of a campaign that is not holding the like: www.teespring.com/createpeaceofmind

Comment: Facebook debugger is a great tool for issues like this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teespring.com%2Fcreatepeaceofmind